# Gulp stream error when using wildcard for containing directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, task

I have a Gulp task...

```
gulp.task('compileJS', function () {
    var jsStream = gulp.src(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/js/assets/**/*.js']);
    jsStream.pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/js'));
});
```

It renders this error when I try and run it...

```
{ [Error: /home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/resources/js/all.js: 'return' outside of function]
  message: '/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/resources/js/all.js: \'return\' outside of function',
  fileName: '/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/resources/js/all.js',
  lineNumber: 161750,
  stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_modules/gulp
-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)\n    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/
Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)\n
 at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/to
ols/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2026:9)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_mod
ules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2168:21)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/a
llen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2073:24)
\n    at block_ (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify

-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2353:20)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/n
ode_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2120:29)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (
/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2
073:24)\n    at if_ (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEnergy/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/ug
lify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2336:44)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/allen/Projects/WWW/SunHorizonEner
gy/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2164:24)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify' }
```

But, it works completely fine if I specify the directory names instead of using the `**` wildcard. I could definitely do that, but it kind of detracts from the scalability of my application...which is one of the main reasons I use a task runner in the first place.

Even stranger, I have another task that does almost the exact same thing, but for SCSS and CSS files...

```
gulp.task('compileCSS', function () {
    var cssStream = gulp.src('resources/styles/CSS/**/*.css');
    var scssStream = gulp.src('resources/styles/SCSS/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError);
    eventStream.concat(cssStream, scssStream)
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/styles'));
});
```

This works just fine! And I'm using the `**` wildcard! I have confirmed that the directory is correct by manually replacing `**` with a directory.

What gives?

Comment: Just a pointer, did you notice that they problem is in uglify? I would try the same thing with a very simple set of directories and files, maybe 2 directories, 2 very simple files each, also, can you set showStack to true? Lastly, if you have webstorm or intellij, you can step through the code in a debugging session

Comment: Well, that's the thing. It seems like it's a problem with uglify, but if I specify every directory by hand rather than the other way, it works just fine.

Comment: I feel really stupid. I just noticed that there is a "dependencies" sub directory which include minimified and non-minified versions of Angular. That's the problem. Should I delete the question?

Comment: It seems like something that could happen to someone else, I would post an answer to your own question